# item selected color in android BottomNavigationView

Tags: android, select, colors, bottomnavigationview

I refer [this](https://medium.com/@hitherejoe/exploring-the-android-design-support-library-bottom-navigation-drawer-548de699e8e0#.vmqn5e5xi). Schedules Activity is appeared when I click Schedules,  but first item color (Favorites) is always selected. It doesn't change Schedules item color from Favorites item color. And also, third item (Music). I use **android:state_checked** NOT **android:state_enabled**." If working with startActivity, it doesn't change Schedules item color from Favorites item color. If not, it change color. How to solve this color select problems.

activity_main.xml

```
app:itemIconTint="@drawable/nav_item_color_state"
app:itemTextColor="@drawable/nav_item_color_state"
app:menu="@menu/bottom_navigation_main"
```

@drawable/nav_item_color_state

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:color="@color/white" android:state_enabled="true" />
    <item android:color="@color/colorPrimaryDark" android:state_enabled="false" />
</selector>
```

Comment: Have you taken separate activities for Schedules, Favourites, and Music ?

Comment: Yes, I separate those three activities

Comment: Anybody found solution on this?

Answer (score 214):

create a color directory in res folder and create your xml file for customize your bottom navigation items:

**res/color/bottom_nav_color.xml:**

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
     <item android:state_checked="true" android:color="@color/your_color" />
     <item android:state_checked="false" android:color="@color/your_color"/>
</selector>
```

and in your `BottomNavigationView` set `app:itemTextColor` and `app:itemIconTint` values to **@color/bottom_nav_color**

```xml
<android.support.design.widget.BottomNavigationView
   xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
   android:id="@+id/main_navigation"
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
   android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
   android:background="@color/actionBarColor"
   app:menu="@menu/my_navigation_items"
   app:itemTextColor="@color/bottom_nav_color"
   app:itemIconTint="@color/bottom_nav_color"/>
```

Comment: You open for me some new in android. Is it hack or just official android sdk?

Comment: @SergBurlaka Hi, there is a function in BottomNavigationView documentation for set itemTextColor value and type of function input is ColorStateList and ColorStateList documentation is in below link https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/res/ColorStateList

Answer (score 23):

1. Make a xml file in the drawable folder with the name of `navigation_view_colored.xml` and put this inside:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
  <item android:state_checked="false" android:color="@color/gray" />
  <item android:state_checked="true" android:color="@color/blue" />
</selector>
```

2. Add the xml you created to `app:itemIconTint`

```
<com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/bottom_navigation"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    app:itemIconTint="@drawable/navigation_view_colored"
    app:itemTextColor="@color/blue"
    app:menu="@menu/bottom_navigation"
    android:background="?android:attr/windowBackground"/>
```

Answer (score 8):

just change `theme`:

create `themes.xml` in `values` and add this style

```
<style name="BottomNavThem" parent="Theme.MaterialComponents.Light.NoActionBar">
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimaryRed</item>
</style>
```

and set to BottomNavigationView

```
<com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView
    android:id="@+id/bottomNavigationView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:menu="@menu/main_navigation_menu"
    android:theme="@style/BottomNavThem"/>
```

Answer (score 6):

here is simple solution to your question

```
<android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
....
app:tabBackground="@drawable/tab_color_selector"
...
/>
```

the selector `res/drawable/tab_color_selector.xml`:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:drawable="@color/tab_background_selected" android:state_selected="true"/>
    <item android:drawable="@color/tab_background_unselected" android:state_checked="false"/>
 </selector>
```

update tab item selector color what your required to.

Answer (score 6):

In my situation, I used [BottomNavigationBarEx](https://github.com/ittianyu/BottomNavigationViewEx) plugin. So, I had to do it like below:

In my **res/layout/layout_navigation_view.xml**:

Added `app:itemIconTint="@drawable/bottom_nav_colors"`. Since, I only used icons. So if you have text add this: `app:itemTextColor="@drawable/bottom_nav_colors"` also.

```
    <com.ittianyu.bottomnavigationviewex.BottomNavigationViewEx
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/bottomNavBar"
        android:background="@drawable/white_grey_border_top"
        app:itemIconTint="@drawable/bottom_nav_colors"
        app:menu="@menu/bottom_navigation_menu" />
```

Then in **res/drawable** directory (because `selector`s need to include in `drawable` or `animatable` directory) add the `selector`(as others mentioned):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:state_checked="false" android:color="@color/grey" />
    <item android:state_checked="true" android:color="@color/blue" />
</selector>
```

Then in **res/values/colors.xml** add your **select** and **unselect** colors, as ex:

```
<color name="grey">#bfbfbf</color>
<color name="blue">#3F51B5</color>
```

Answer (score 1):

Have you heard about the wrapper project called BottomBar of Roughike which makes the use of BottomNavigationView easier? Project can be found [here](https://github.com/roughike/BottomBar).

I suggest you to use this project which is up to date and has contribution in a high level. If you refer to use this, You can simply insert the below code to change the colors when clicked on tabs and do much more customized stuff:

```
TabLayout tabLayout = (TabLayout) findViewById(R.id.tabLayout);
Tab tab = newTab().setIcon(new BitmapDrawable(getResources(), icon)));
tab.getIcon().setColorFilter(Color.parseColor("#7E7E7E"), PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_IN);

tabLayout.addOnTabSelectedListener(new TabLayout.OnTabSelectedListener() {
                          @Override public void onTabSelected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {
                            if (tab != null && tab.getIcon() != null) {
                              tab.getIcon().clearColorFilter();
                              }
                          }
                          @Override public void onTabUnselected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {
                            if (tab != null && tab.getIcon() != null) {
                              tab.getIcon()
                                  .setColorFilter(Color.parseColor("#7E7E7E"),
                                      PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_IN);
                            }
                          }
                          @Override public void onTabReselected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {
                          }
                        });
                      }
                    }
                  });
```

So basically what I do here, I color unselected tabs to `#7E7E7E` and clear the filter for coloring from selected ones so they appear with their original color of their icon. Of course, you can fill with another color when selected as well, that's up to you.

Hope this helps you!

Cheers,

Renc

Comment: It means using tabLayout instead of RelativeLayout. where is tabLayout?

Comment: @StevenLin if you refer to the GitHub project given, you can find the library for this usage.

Comment: tabLayout is shown underline, I want to use logo and text only. Sir!

Answer (score -1):

Other answers using the drawable selector didn't work for me.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:state_checked="true" android:color="@color/colorPrimary" />
    <item android:color="@color/bottomnavUnselectedColor"  />
</selector>
```

This worked in my case removing the `state_checked="false"`

```
<com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView
        android:id="@+id/bottomnav"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/transparent_rect"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:itemIconTint="@drawable/bottomnav_selector"
        app:menu="@menu/bottomnav_menu"/>
```